# Counting occurrences in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I've been brought on last minute to sort out tent allocation for a festival of about 1500 people. Their ticket sales are a spreadsheet on Google Drive. I have never done this kind of thing before (I'm an English teacher), but I'm good with software, generally, and have experience with basic programming functions.

Tents will be allocated based on 3-day passes (`sheet 1`), and 2-day passes (`sheet 2`). The unique identifier is ticket number, with other details in separate fields.

`Sheet 3` (my job) will show the individual tents, and who is inside.

I'll allocate a tent number in a new column within the sales sheets (sheets `1` and `2` - based on customer request). I want to parse these columns to `sheet 3`, such that `sheet 3` displays the tent number, and details of attendees inside that tent (using unique identifier of ticket number).

I'm guessing that each tent will be an array?

As an extra challenge, I want to bound the tents to limits (4-man, 6-, 10-man tent), so that if the number of occurrences of tent x exceeds its bounds, it returns an error.

Comment: Thanks pnuts. I guess tent limits would be held as a defined limit for each tent (as a data array)? It's an optional limit. I can overcome it by listing each tent as "tent 43 - 6 man", then if it has more than 6 entries I would manually go back and look at sales sheets. I was just thinking array limit so people dont enter excess tent allocation in main sheets.

What I need to pull from sheet 1 and 2 is the occurrences of a tent number, then the attendee details of said occurrence is copied to tent sheet.

Sorry, I'm new to this, but trying to describe situation in as much detail as possible.

Comment: btw, my knowledge of the term "data array" comes from programming briefly in c, where u can set bounds on an array. I dunno how arrays work in google spreadsheets. Like I said I'm new to all this. Thanks so much.

Comment: Here's a dummy version of the event spreadsheet as given to me. I've stripped out all attendee data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am7vpLQs1EBkdEtYZDYzVGdNQmMyNmpPSmRQZGkzc3c&usp=sharing

Comment: So in column I, the tent number will be entered. I want to parse this to a third sheet, which will display the tent, and everybody who is in it. ideally, I'd also like it so that if someone attempts to enter a tent number in main ticket sales spreadsheet for a tent that already has capacity, it returns an error.

Comment: thx. forgot to remove details from sheet 2. all contact details should be gone now

Comment: Your solution works elegantly, thanks so much. Is there any way to reverse the ordering such that the fields that have been allocated a tent appear at the top? At the moment if a tent number is entered on sheet 1 or 2, then the resulting data update appears at the very bottom of spreadsheet 3.

Comment: I just want to add, You've probably just greatly assisted in making about 1500 festival attendees have a really great time. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks so much. ALthough it shows the tent number in descending order, it at least shows the allocated tents at top of sheet. Once all tents have been assigned and there are no empty cells, I can remove the desc. You've helped me alot. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this. Its made an ENORMOUS difference in  organization this year.
Now that I have these spreadsheets working smoothly, I want to query the columns with tent allocations and total the occurances of each tent number. The tent number and then the number of occurances will be displayed in two new columns. Is this possible?

Comment: thanks pnuts, unfortunately I need it spelled out to me :P I'll create a separate thread so it doesn't extend further, along with some sample data Thanks again.

Comment: I created a new question on this link:http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70143/how-to-count-occurances-of-number-in-a-column-group-and-total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some finishing touches were applied that have been the subject of another question where there seems to be recognition that a a satisfactory overall conclusion has been reached. This contribution to that from this post was essentially a formula:

```
=query('3 Day - Friday Bus'!A5:I10,"Select I, A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H order BY I desc")
```

to select data from a range in another sheet, slightly rearrange it and order it (descending to avoid blanks floating to the top).