# How to count occurrences of number in a column, group and total

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet for a festival. Unique identifier is ticket number. I want to query the column with tent number, to automatically generate two columns. First column has tent number. Second column has total number of occurrences of that tent number.

[image: sample data. Column K and L are auto generated]

I want Column K and L to autogenerate tent number and number of occupants based on column J. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select ColumnJ. Data > Pivot table report..., Rows - Add field `Tent#`, Values - Add field `Tent#`. Click on down arrow next to "Summarise by: SUM" and select COUNT. Select the PT, Ctrl+c, got to K2(?) in your data sheet and Ctrl+v.

Comment: A.Maz.ING. Again. You've just saved hours and hours of work. We're now totally sorted for tents. The process can be handled entirely by me now. You've saved us alot of time, money and effort. Thanks so much

Answer (score -1):

I want to find the number of occurrences of, say, "X" within a range of cells, where "X" may occur multiple times within any cell.